# "motion picture" vs. "video"

Tags: meaning

[From Oxford Languages](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/motion%20picture)

> motion picture: a cinema film

According to the definition, some types of video are not motion pictures, such as screen recording, animation, is my understanding correct?

Comment: The term _motion picture_ goes back long before video technology, when moving pictures, whether live action or animation, were photographed on reels of film. We still use the old terms for cinema films (movies) even though the technology has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary gives the following definition for *motion picture*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/motion-picture?q=motion%20picture).

> (especially North American English) a film that is made for the cinema

Yes, a screen recording isn't a motion picture because it's not a film made for the cinema, but *motion picture* is still used for an animation movie.

Comment: Thank you. "a film that is made for the cinema" indicates there is another type of film that is not made for the cinema, is it? If yes, what that type is?

Comment: An event recorded by a camera is a film. If I record, for example, a birthday party, that is still a film. Then, there are also films for television.